# ThinkPad LCD backlight steps issue on Linux

Tags: linux, thinkpad, backlight, function-keys

I have a Thinkpad Edge E130, and the LCD screen's backlight has 15 *hardware* steps.

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness 
$ 15
```

I'm currently running Linux with LXDE as desktop environment, and this is the problem:

- Before login to LXDE, the backlight works fine. With Fn+F6/Fn+F7 I can set all the hardware steps
- After login, I can set only 8 steps. I think that both LXDE and ACPI increase one step for every Fn+F7 pressure (8*2 "=" 15).

I've tried to add the following kernel boot parameters:

- `acpi_backligh=vendor`
- `acpi_backligh=vendor, acpi_osi=Linux`
- `acpi_backligh=vendor, thinkpad-acpi.brightness_enable=1` (according to [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight) wiki)

In all the case the backlight completely stops to work, so I think that `acpi_backligh=vendor` is not helpful in my case.

I have also tried with `video.use_bios_initial_backlight=0` kernel parameter, but nothing seems to happen (always 8 steps).

Suggestions?

Comment: I am using xfce4 on a T510 and I have 8 steps up and 5 steps down, I recognized irregularities in the pattern but didn't really care. Until now… damn you…!

Comment: @Informaficker Sorry! I hope that my fix can help you.

Comment: Please don't edit your solution into your question, write an answer yourself. This is totally OK here on StackExchange (actually it is the way you should do it here). You should accept your answer as soon as you are able to, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching, I find the following solution: just a simple

```
# echo -n 0 > /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled
```

Of course this needs to be done at every boot (the way depends on the specific distro).

Many thanks to [arch linux guys](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=139610)

Comment: There is no need to do it at every boot, it should be enough to specify the parameter value for `modprobe` in a file like `/etc/modprobe.d/video-local.conf` with the line: `options video brightness_switch_enabled=1`